# What is the relationship between MIDP and JME (and Android)?

Tags: android, midp, java-me

What is the distinction between MIDP and JME?

How do both relate to Android? As far as I understand JME isn't supported on Android - is that correct?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MIDP stands for [Mobile Information Device Profile](http://java.sun.com/products/midp/). JME refers to [Java Micro Edition](http://java.sun.com/javame/index.jsp) and is a striped down version of the Java (standard edition) API suitable for mobiles and embedded devices.

The Android OS and accompanying Dalvik VM, handles "full Java"*, that is, it is not a stripped down version of the API as Java ME is.

A related question is found here: [Moving to Android from J2ME](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64745/moving-to-android-from-j2me)

* As @synic points out, the Android OS does not provide Swing/AWT for instance.

Comment: Looking at that, it would appear that if you're working on Android you don't need to worry about MIDP - is that correct?

Comment: I don't think you have to "worry" about it in the sense that it's impossible to write an app on Android that adheres to MIDP.  If you were developing for BlackBerry it's possible to write one app that can run on both BlackBerries and MIDP devices, but you end up with a lowest common denominator app, so I would probably never do that (unless it was the year 2001).

Comment: Thanks Brandon, I get you - MIDP is the most minimalist mobile spec you can get, and once you're writing for more powerful devices you can just ignore it ..

Comment: It is missing some parts... but they are parts you won't need, such as AWT and Swing