# What would be best Alternative to J2ME?

Tags: java-me

Hai Friends, 
         I want to know what is the best alternative to J2ME.
         When i referred Net i found the following, but i am still confusing that, which one is best alternative to J2ME.

```
   1. Android
   2. SuperWABA
   3. JBed
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/64745/moving-to-android-from-j2me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[this will Help you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1414288/j2me-vs-android-vs-iphone-vs-symbian-vs-windows-ce)

Comment: @ FosterZ: Thank You for ur Response, but i want to know more information about SuperWABA, and JBed. Is they are a proper alternative to J2ME, because for android i searched and got information from developer guide,but what about the other two. that's why i posted this question friend.

Answer (score 0):

Well, judging from your avatar, I'd say alternative 1.

Besides, the android-alternative will have, by far, a larger and better community. (Have you seen a lot of answered `SuperWABA` or `JBed` questions here on SO lately? :)